# doing a line graph with jfreechart in excel file

Tags: java, graph

I am doing a lineal graph in java with JFreeChart, i was checking in internet and this is that i have at the moment:

```
DefaultKeyedValues data = new DefaultKeyedValues();
data.addValue("01/04/2012",7);
data.addValue("01/05/2012",5);
data.addValue("01/06/2012",6);
data.addValue("01/07/2012",2); 

CategoryDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset("Population", data);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Population","Date","Population",dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);

LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
renderer.setBaseLinesVisible(true);
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setRenderer(0, renderer);

NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();        
numberAxis.setRange(new Range(0,10));

CategoryAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);
```

The problem comes when I try to insert more categories in the linear graph, I don't know how to do it. I need to do 3 categories more.

[actual graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48c6e.png)

I need use DefaultKeyedValues or some series collection that let me use String param with double/int param. I want to make a generalized method that passes different formats of dates, and the method always draw a graph. In the photo of the example I am passing a date range 'dd-MM-yyyy' but later I will pass a format 'MM-yyyy'.

Edit: Okey i find this example in internet that solves my problem.

[enter link description here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedCategoryPlotDemo1.htm)

Comment: take a look at [JFreeChartDualAxisDemo2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDualAxisDemo2.htm)

Comment: It is using TimeSeriesCollection. I need use DefaultKeyedValues or some series collection that let me use String param with double/int param. 
I need to make a generalized method that passes different formats of dates, and the method always draw a graph. In the photo of the example I am passing a date range dd / MM / yyyy but later I will pass a format MM / yyyy. I can't use TimesSeriesCollection because it need pass a date format:
 
    TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Random Data 1", Month.class);

 This "Montah.class"  only will get a Date object which format is "MM/yyyy"